# Punti di sospensione per un elenco: come utilizzarli in italiano

Tags: punctuation, typography, list

È possibile utilizzare  i punti di sospensione "…" per omettere di scrivere l'intero elenco di elementi di un insieme? Utilizzarli in pratica al posto di locuzione come **"etc. etc."**. Non trovo molti riferimenti al riguardo nelle grammatiche.  Quale delle seguenti opzioni è la più corretta?

Con lo spazio:

> i quadrupedi (cani, gatti, cavalli …)

Senza spazio:

> i quadrupedi (cani, gatti, cavalli…)

Con la virgola:

> i quadrupedi (cani, gatti, … )

Comment: See also: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/whats-the-correct-way-of-writing-a-non-terminated-list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bice Mortara Garavelli nel suo *Prontuario di punteggiatura*, Laterza 2003 (pag. 113) descrive tra gli usi dei puntini di sospensione quello di “far capire che un elenco può continuare indefinitamente (il loro valore è quello di *eccetera* e di espressioni consimili)” e quindi il loro uso è senz'altro ammissibile. Non fa esempi di questo uso specifico, ma visto che lo fa rientrare nel discorso generale dei possibili usi dei puntini di sospensione, evidentemente anche qui vanno usati come in tutti gli altri casi, e cioè senza lo spazio prima...

---

Aggiungo che oggi ho sfogliato in libreria il libro di Simone Fornara *La punteggiatura* (Carocci 2010) e lì trovo che in un esempio di elenco con i puntini mette la virgola seguita dai puntini senza spazio.

Nel complesso deduco che la norma non sia unica, forse perché l'uso dei puntini di sospensione per generalizzare un elenco è più recente e informale e meno “canonico” dell'etc. e simili, e quindi non ha un trattamento univoco.

Comment: Grazie, vedendo il [link](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/puntini_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) che ha postato @rano sembra che si spazino sempre ...

Comment: No, non si spaziano...

Answer (score 4):

Sì se la progressione è identificabile dai primi elementi esplicitati. Inoltre andrebbe ripetuto il separatore di interpunzione (nel tuo caso la virgola) dopo l'ultimo elemento e di conseguenza esso dovrebbe essere seguito da uno spazio.

Quindi

```
i quadrupedi (cani, gatti, … )
```

è la forma corretta (anche se quei soli due elementi dell'elenco non mi paiono così rappresentativi della classe quadrupedi)

Comment: Hai una fonte o è una tua opinione?

Comment: Non sottomano, direi quindi che è una regola sia empirica (la necessità della rappresentatività) che teorica (il dover far seguire uno spazio alla virgola)

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/puntini_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/ qui sono usati senza virgola precedente, ma pur sempre con spaziatura antecedente. La virgola 'suona' maggiormente corretta ai miei orecchi

Comment: Ok, penso l'adotterò forse è una derivazione dalla matematica...

Comment: Potrebbe di fatto essere una descrizione estensionale di un insieme

Comment: A scuola mi hanno insegnato che non si mette la virgola, e non si spaziano...

Comment: @Roberto A scuola probabilmente erano usati in un contesto diverso. Dal punto di vista matematico è usuale usare la virgola *e* spaziarli quando si sta descrivendo un insieme. Fonte: `The TeXbook`, e anche la pagina di wikipedia [Set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation); nota *3, ... , 100* contro *3,...,100*.

Comment: mmm sembra che [qui](http://books.google.it/books?id=BCRXQfia26wC&pg=PA73&dq=punti+di+sospensione&hl=it&sa=X&ei=Ywe3Uu-eMqm70QWdx4H4DQ&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=punti%20di%20sospensione&f=false) sia di altro avviso....

Comment: @Bakuriu questo é un altro caso, ed é quando i punti di sospensione sostituiscono non la parte finale, ma alcuni elementi interni ad un insieme. Non é il caso "al posto di etc. etc." a cui la domanda di DaG si riferisce.

Comment: @Roberto il caso di Bakuriu è affine alla domanda, quello linkato invece da G M no

Comment: @rano: Forse ho perso il filo, ma mi pare che il link di G M sia esattamente pertinente alla domanda. Fra gli esempi riportati lì c'è «Coltivano riso, granturco, segale...» che è esattamente un esempio di elenco parziale come quello con i cani e i gatti, no?

Comment: @Bakuriu: Anch'io ho pensato all'uso matematico, ma la notazione scientifica ha un proprio codice che non sempre si può riportare di peso all'uso linguistico o tipografico generale.

Comment: @rano Come fa a non essere pertinente c'è scritto: "per indicare che l'elencazione potrebbe continuare e in un certo senso hanno valore di eccetera:"

Comment: ho confuso i link chiedo venia : )

Comment: sulla questione 'spazio sì/spazio no' faccio notare che un conto è l'italiano scritto (su carta) ed un conto quello trascritto in digitale (dove lo spazio è a tutti gli effetti un carattere, con il suo codice ASCII). Scrivere con due 'spazi' consecutivi è scorretto nell'italiano trascritto su computer (no su una macchina da scrivere), ma le regole tipografiche per il digitale sono successive. Le possibili eredità della scrittura cartacea o dattiloscritta sono da tenere in conto. I formalismi matematici per la tipografia, leggasi TeX, insegnano ad avere rigore anche nell'uso degli spazi.

Comment: Questa risposta mi sembra completamente sbagliata. La gran parte dei testi usa la forma senza spazio e senza virgola, che sicuramente è lecita e direi che sia la forma di gran lunga più diffusa. Si potrebbe discutere se la forma con la virgola sia ammissibile, ma di certo non è obbligatoria.

Per esempio si veda Treccani: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/puntini_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/

Answer (score 0):

Per amore di correttezza, i puntini di sospensione vanno messi senza essere preceduti da uno spazio, a gruppi da tre e con uno spazio dopo la sospensione. Se dopo la sospensione, all'interno della parentesi, avessi intenzione di proseguire il discorso, allora devi farlo mettendo la lettera maiuscola alla prima parola di questa nuova frase. 
Spesso nelle pubblicazioni scientifiche vengono usati per indicare elenchi circoscritti anche da virgole, ad es: (1, 2, 3, ... , 10).

In ogni caso, credo che difficilmente qualcuno in Italia considererebbe errore l'uso dello spazio prima dei punti di sospensione.

Answer (score 0):

Concordo pienamente con @rano. E provo ad aggiungere altro.

La spaziatura non ha un significato totalmente indipendente dalla stampa, essendo strettamente legata anche a discorsi **tipografici**. Lo **spazio**, ad esempio, è l'unico elemento tipografico (oltre naturalmente ad *a capo*) che consente il passaggio da un rigo all'altro senza utilizzare il trattino (`pal-[a capo]la`), motivo per cui la maggior parte dei segni di punteggiatura vuole lo spazio a destra e non a sinistra (non vogliamo mica che un rigo inizi con la virgola o col punto?).

Fatta questa premessa tutto si costruisce più o meno da sé. Mi sento di dire che i puntini di sospensione "ereditano la spaziatura di ciò che sostituiscono". A tal proposito ci sono delle fonti e degli esempi --- tratti da documenti di una certa autorevolezza --- che non trovo in disaccordo con questa mia intuizione.

- [Qui](http://www.grammatica-italiana.it/puntini-di-sospensione.html) trovo scritto che *dopo (e non prima!) i tre punti bisogna sempre lasciare uno spazio, tranne quando sono seguiti dal punto esclamativo o interrogativo o dalla chiusura di virgolette o parentesi*, cioè essi non vogliono spazio a seguire esattamente quando tale spazio non è richiesto dal carattere seguente (`!`, `?`, e `"` e così via non vogliono spazio prima di sé).
- Allo stesso *link* c'è anche scritto che *Bisogna poi ricordare che dopo i tre puntini non va mai la lettera maiuscola a meno che si concluda il periodo.* Anche in questo caso dopo i puntini di sospensione la scelta di maiuscola/minuscola dipende da cosa i puntini hanno sostituito (qualcosa che terminava con un punto o no?).
- In [questa](http://www.dei.unipd.it/~addetto/manuali_online/ArteLaTeX.pdf) introduzione/guida al più famoso e potente programma di composizione tipografica al mondo, LaTeX, potete trovare alcuni esempi dell'uso dei puntini di sospensione (nonché la necessità di tenerli sempre uniti) e, in particolare, un esempio dell'uso di puntini preceduti dalla virgola e da essa spaziati (pag. 9).

Concludendo, secondo la mia modesta opinione, corrette spaziature sono le seguenti.

> i quadrupedi (cani, gatti, ...)
>
> i quadrupedi (cani, gatti...)